# Can't catch python warning with warnings.catch_warnings()

Tags: python, pdf, warnings, python-camelot

I'am using the [Camelot](https://github.com/atlanhq/camelot) library in python to read tables from pdf's.

If There is no table recognized, but something else (like a text), the library gives a warning: `UserWarning: No tables found in table area 1 [stream.py:365]`.
My idea was to catch this Warning with `warnings.catch_warnings()` function.

This is my Code:

```
with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as w:
    # reading tables from pdf
    parsed_tables = camelot.read_pdf(
        tmp_file.name,
        pages=page,
        flavor="stream",
        row_tol=row_tol,
        table_areas=["30,480,790,100"],
        surpress_stdout=False
    )
    # warning.warn("TEST")
    print("warning", w)
```

My problem is that variable w is always empty. If I uncomment the "TEST" warning the warning appears in variable w (it works with my own warning).

I searched the library for warning filters but I didn't find any.
I tried to add `warnings.filterwarnings("default")` or `warnings.simplefilter("always")`.
Why can't I catch this warning? Is it because it occurs in the library and not in my Code?

Answer (score 1):

Please try that exact thing with the `action` set as `ignore`. When you wrote `always`, you requested for warnings to be shown in all instances...

As a **little recap**, you can use a context manager to catch the warnings. You need to specify the action when the context manager catches the warning. By default, it might not do what you want.

- Before `Python 3.11`, you had to write the desired action on a different line (and it is the way to do it, I checked in the docs, see below).
- After `Python 3.11`, you can in a very nice way and concise way pass the action to the constructor of the context manager.

See example below.

```
# works in python 3.8: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/warnings.html
import warnings
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    fn_triggering_warnings()

# works in python 3.11: https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/warnings.html
import warnings
with warnings.catch_warnings(action="ignore"):
    fn_triggering_warnings()
```